# Combine (SUM) data from 4 files on RHEL7.4

Tags: linux, shell

I have 4 distinct files each having the same structure  Call  then 101.txt to 104.txt.  This is a snippet as an example

```
#Per-Day Traffic Summary
#-----------------------
#    date          received  delivered   deferred    bounced     rejected
#    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jan 31 2018     28131      34709       1305        392      34647 
    Feb  1 2018     32863      40714       1674        497      41694 
    Feb  2 2018     31113      38724       2353        543      41251 
    Feb  3 2018     28336      36913       3201        799      40219 
    Feb  4 2018     28442      36951       2257        865      39910 
    Feb  5 2018     29837      39448       1112        486      38566 
    Feb  6 2018     29844      38999       1609        497      39683
```

I'd like to combine the "received" from each file, the "delivered"  from each file, etc. , per day in order to generate a file for gnuplot.  For instance if 101 and 102 had the same amount for 31 Jan the received would be 56262.  I have 4 files in all to combine into one output file with the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a perl script:

```
perl sum.pl 101.txt 102.txt 103.txt 104.txt > result.txt
```

where sum.pl contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %processed_header;
my %data;

while (<>)
{
   if (/^(#.+)/)
   {
      print unless ($processed_header{$1});
      $processed_header{$1} = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      next unless(/(\w\w\w\s+\d+\s\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/);

      $data{$1}{'ord'} = scalar(keys(%data)) unless ($data{$1});

      $data{$1}{'rec'} += $2;
      $data{$1}{'del'} += $3;
      $data{$1}{'def'} += $4;
      $data{$1}{'bou'} += $5;
      $data{$1}{'rej'} += $6;
   }
}

for (sort { $data{$a}{'ord'} <=> $data{$b}{'ord'} } (keys(%data)))
{
   printf("%14s %10d %10d %10d %10d %10d\n",
          $_, $data{$_}{'rec'}, $data{$_}{'del'},
          $data{$_}{'def'}, $data{$_}{'bou'}, $data{$_}{'rej'});
}
```

Comment: This works great! but if Column 1 (date) had numbers instead of the letters, you couldn't use "ord" there right?  Is there a way to do this without qualifying the data in column 1?

But I really appreciate the education here.

Comment: Well, the 'ord' is for the order that the data lines were read.
The data is stored in a hashtable that has no ordering.

The field in column 1 is read as '3 alphabetic chars followed by some space followed by some digits some spaces and some digits'.

That is where the `(\w\w\w\s+\d+\s+\d+)` stands for.

Comment: It would also work with something like `(\S.{10})` meaning: 'a non space followed by 10 chars'. 

You could use something like that if your column 1 would be formatted in an other way.

Comment: Suppose another file is like this>

`#Per-Hour Traffic Daily Average
#------------------------------
#    time          received  delivered   deferred    bounced     rejected
#    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    0000-0100         909       1257        174         29       1426 
    0100-0200         876       1243        177         34       1380 `
 and I used 

      `next unless(/(\S.{10})/);`
The rest of your script is same.  The first column comes out right but it doesn't sum.